# Adding or condition in for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

How can I add `or` in `for loop` check?
for example:

```
for ($i=1; ($i <= $untilPoint) or ($i <= $points); $i++){
.. code ...
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work (does it?), then you could turn it into a `do`/`while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you typed is valid PHP. For example, this program:

```
<?
$untilPoint = 3;
$points = 5;
for ($i=1; ($i <= $untilPoint) or ($i <= $points); $i++){
    echo("$i\n");
}
?>
```

prints this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

(tested in PHP 5.2.17, run from the Bash prompt).

That said, I wonder if maybe you really need `and` rather than `or`? If `$i` is an index into an array of points, where `$points` is the number of points and `$untilPoint` is an arbitrary cutoff, then you want `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done, probably it runs slightly faster.
You can separate with , see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php for more information

```
<?
$untilPoint = 3;
$points = 5;
for ($i=1; $i <= $untilPoint, $i <= $points; $i++){
    echo($i , "\n");
}
?>
```